# Not able to execute jar file. Getting NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, ant, jar, executable-jar

I have created a executable jar file using build.

```
<target name="deploy" depends="compile">
<jar jarfile="${deploy.home}/${app.name}.jar" basedir="${build.home}">
<manifest>
<attribute name="Main-Class" value="abc.xyz"/>
</manifest>
</jar>
```

Here the xyz call has the main method to execute the whole program..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        File buildFile = new File("build.xml");
        Project p = new Project();
        p.setUserProperty("ant.file", buildFile.getAbsolutePath());
        p.init();
        ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
        p.addReference("ant.projectHelper", helper);
        helper.parse(p, buildFile);
        p.executeTarget(p.getDefaultTarget());
}
```

The jar file is being created successfuly. When I execute the like `java -jar appname.jar`, it is throwing exception --

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/Project
        at abc.xyz.main(xyz.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.Project
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
```

The project class not found. Its there in `ant.jar`.

But when i execute the `abc.java` class simply by on command prompt java abc its working fine.

Pleased help me to get the cause? and its solution.

Comment: can you please explain `But when i execute the xyz.java class simply by on command prompt java abc.java its working fine` you have two classes? one calling each other? can you post the whole code of the two classes (omitting the not-interesting parts) I need to check your package declaration

Comment: You have to add required libraries to the class-path declared in the manifest of your app-jar. If your application needs ant.jar you have to tell Java about it.

Comment: Thanks Gianmarco, It was typo error, I have edited, Its only one main class. No package issue. its working fine on eclipse.

Comment: Thanks to @Holger. I understand its looking for the project class, But while compilation and jar creation I have provided the all req jars references. Then in my project if I have used 200 jars while compilation. Do I need to give 200 jars references. I am bit confused. Please suggest..

Comment: @Holger -- Could you please tell me how to add required libraries to the class-path declared in the manifest of your app-jar?

Answer (score 0):

Add required libraries to the class path of the jar

```
<target name="deploy" depends="compile">
<jar jarfile="${deploy.home}/${app.name}.jar" basedir="${build.home}">
<manifest>
<attribute name="Main-Class" value="abc.xyz"/>
<attribute name="Class-Path" value="ant.jar"/>
</manifest>
</jar>
```

If you need more than one jar you have to separate them by spaces.

Comment: The path should be relative to the location of the application jar containing the manifest. So you should know the directory structure you want to deploy. You should always avoid absolute paths if you intent to deploy an application so it can run under different environments.

Comment: Holger- So Nice of you. But sorry its not helping me. Still same error. But in manifest file i can see classes are added relatively. Do i need to include lib folder in the app.jar? Thanks for help..

Comment: No the referenced libraries have to be *relative to* the app.jar not inside it.

Comment: Must be something related to information not contained in your question and comments. You might try putting all jars into the same directory and set the class-path to the jar names without any path prefix.

Comment: I have added the path now i am getting this error --Exception in thread "main" Could not load the version information. at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.getAntVersion(Main.java:956) at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.initProperties(Project.java:308) at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.init(Project.java:295).. Please help

Comment: I think an ant installation consist of more than just a single jar. But that would be another question.

Comment: The way i used is <jar destfile="build/main/checksites.jar">
    <fileset dir="build/main/classes"/>
    <restrict>
     <name name="**/*.class"/>
     <archives>
       <zips>
         <fileset dir="lib/main" includes="**/*.jar"/>
       </zips>
     </archives>
    </restrict>
    <manifest>
      <attribute name="Main-Class"
            value="com.acme.checksites.Main"/>
    </manifest>
  </jar> ,